# Why AWS snapshot is not removed after de registering AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I wonder, why AWS snapshot is not removed after deregistering AWS AMI?

If I create a new AWS AMIs today and deregister all old AMIs, and do a search in snapshots for started less than today, and deleted them manually, what will impact on running EC2, and AMI created today?

Comment: You can still create a server from the snapshot even after the AMI is gone. Why would AWS delete your backups? You can delete snapshots manually any time you like.

Comment: I thought after deleting AWS AMI ( `de registering AWS AMI`) , associated snapshot will be deleted automatically.

Comment: For me the snapshot wanishes in less than an hour after deregistering the AMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my Ex colleague given below answer

**Manually delete all the snapshot, the UI will tell u if the snapshot is used by an AMI**

Comment: This is a bad technique and should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you deregister an AMI image, the associated EBS snapshots are not deleted.

You must delete the EBS snapshots after the AMI is deregistered.